# Prolog to count all the leaf nodes in a binary tree

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

I need to count all the internal nodes of a binary tree using prolog I can count all of the nodes using the following code

```
internal(tree(_,L,R), I) :- internal(L, I2), internal(R, I3), I is I2 + I3 + 1.
internal(nil, 0).
```

And I thought that by changing the base case to

```
internal(tree(_,nil, nil), 0).
```

I could get it to work but it returns false.

here is a test case that should return 4 internal(tree(8,tree(5,tree(2,nil,nil),tree(7,nil,nil)),  tree(9,nil,tree(15,tree(11,nil,nil),nil))),I).

Could anyone tell me where my mistake is?
Thanks

After reading your suggestions I've got this but it still fails.

```
internal(tree(_,L,R), I) :- internal(L, I2), internal(R, I3), I is I2 + I3. 
internal(tree(_,nil, R), I):- !, internal(R, I3), I is I3 + 1. 
internal(tree(_,L, nil), I):- !, internal(L, I3), I is I3 + 1.
internal(tree(_,nil, nil), 0).
internal(nil, 0).
```

Comment: Hint: what is `+1` doing here?

Comment: Is your call here using `l` as result? `l` is *not* a variaable, but a constiers.so you should use *uppercase* v identifiers.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the call is using uppercase i as a result, not l, and as far as I understand the +1 is adding 1 to every node after a solution for the base cases has been found which would return 0

Comment: But here you have a `tree(_, nil, tree(_, _, _))` in your example. How does this matches the inductive, or base case if you removed `internal(nil, 0)`?

Comment: my reasoning is that it would never get to the nil base case as it would return 0 when it got to cases such as tree(11,nil,nil), then that would be true and return 0 without ever actually getting to the nil case

Comment: but if you have a `tree(_, nil, tree(_, _, _))`, then the left child is `nil`, and the right one a `tree`, so the basecase is *not* sufficient, nor is the inductive satisfying, since it will call `internal/2` in the children, hence it will call `internal(nil, I1)`.

Comment: @AlejandroValdes Willem's point is that your predicate ignores the case where you may have one leg of the tree `nil`, but the other populated. Your predicate assumes that the tree, or any leg of the tree, either has both branches populated, or both branches `nil`. Thus, the case where only one branch is `nil` will always fail.

Comment: Yes thanks @WillemVanOnsem, and lurker after reading your suggestions I've edited my post with a more thoughtful solution but it still fails.

Comment: @AlejandroValdes: but now `tree(_, nil, nil)` will fire `internal(tree(_,L,R), I)`, and `internal(tree(_,nil, R), I)`, since the second has a "cut", it will not backtrack anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the predicate to:

```
internal(tree(_,nil, nil), 0).
internal(tree(_,L,R), I) :- internal(L, I2), internal(R, I3), I is I2 + I3 + 1.
```

then this will fail for trees with a `nil` child and a non-`nil` child this will fail.

Indeed: if the tree is `tree(1, nil, tree(2, nil, nil))`, then Prolog will first try to satisfy the base case, but sine `nil` is not equal to a `tree(_, nil, nil)`, that fails. Next it aims to satisfy the recursive case, and first unifies `L = nil`, and `R = tree(2, nil, nil)`. Now it calls `internal(L, I2)`, but since `internal(nil, I1)` can not be satisfied it fails.

We can thus first construct a predicate that satisfies if the two subtrees result in an internal node:

```
isinternal(tree(_, _, _), _).
isinternal(_, tree(_, _, _)).
```

so this predicate succeeds if at least one of the subtrees is a `tree(_, _, _).`. Now we can use this predicate to count the number of internal nodes:

```
internal(nil, 0).
internal(tree(_, nil, nil), 0).
internal(tree(_, L, R), I) :-
    isinternal(L, R),
    internal(L, NL),
    internal(R, NR),
    I is NL + NR + 1.
```

The above can be improved in terms of readability. I leave this as an exercise.